# setContentView is using non-SDK interface

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator

When I run my application in an emulator with the API 28, the console gives me the following warning:

> W/oaristachimene: Accessing hidden method
>   Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
>   (light greylist, reflection) W/oaristachimene: Accessing hidden method
>   Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light
>   greylist, reflection)

I have been debugging it and I found out that it comes from the call: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`, so is there another way to set the layout of an activity or is this method going to be updated so that it doesn't throws that warning when running on a device with android API 28?.

Comment: You should show at least the class that is crashing so we can take a look the code

Comment: So I start the template Android project included in Android Studio 2020.3.1 Canary 13 and out-of-the-box am greeted with a whole bunch of these. :O And indeed, the template calls `setContentView`. Welcome to Android, I guess.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For the warnings in the question, `computeFitSystemWindows` and `makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows` are actually used by the support library or androidx library through reflection. You can verify it by simply searching those two methods in the `AppCompatDelegateImpl`.

Hopefully this can be fixed later.

**Update 1**

Recently when I test app in Firebase Test Lab, these 2 APIs and some other APIs are marked

> One possible root cause for this warning is Google-owned library UI Toolkit. No action need be taken at this time.

Or

> One possible root cause for this warning is Google-owned library Android WebView. No action need be taken at this time.

Comment: It is now September 2020, and with up to date dependencies I still get this message. My content view definitely only contains android supplied view classes.

Comment: Feb 2021 and these warning still... persists

Comment: I am also getting the same warning. Just commenting for any future updates.

Comment: same here and it is april 2, 2021. I guess they must be so harmless. I wont worry about them for now. Need help with Renderscript compatability issues after Android P

Comment: Hey @i_o I also came here on April 2 2021. I guess I'll continue to ignore the pre-launch report.

Comment: Still here in Feb 2022

Comment: Still here at May 2022.

Comment: Nov 2022, for God's sake, the warning is still around.

Comment: Still here at July 2023

Answer (score 6):

Chances are good that the layout id you’re passing to `setContentView()` contains some view from a 3rd-party library that uses non-SDK interfaces. This warning is telling you that this is happening, but all you can do is

- Wait for the 3rd party to fix their library
- Remove those 3rd-party views from your layout

For now, this is only a warning; nothing bad will actually happen. But in *future* versions of Android, it might *become* a real problem. The system is just giving you time to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a `warning`.

You should read the [Restrictions on non-SDK interfaces documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces).

> Android 9 (API level 28) introduces new restrictions on the use of non-SDK interfaces, whether directly, via reflection, or via JNI. These restrictions are applied whenever an app references a non-SDK interface or attempts to obtain its handle using reflection or JNI. For more information about this decision, see [Improving Stability by Reducing Usage of non-SDK Interfaces](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/improving-stability-by-reducing-usage.html).
>
> In general, apps should only use the officially documented parts of the classes in the SDK. In particular, this means that you should not plan to access methods or fields that are not listed in the SDK when you interact with a class via semantics such as reflection.

Answer (score 1):

For those getting `Accessing hidden method XYZ` on Android 9 (Pie, API 28):

Some methods greylisted in Android 9 were then whitelisted in Android 10. Before looking for any alternatives to greylisted methods check https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/non-sdk-q#greylist-now-public

This does notapply to the methods in OP's question (`computeFitSystemWindows`, `makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows`) at the moment but may change in future Android releases.

See also https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/non-sdk-q#greylist-now-restricted which presents:

> non-SDK interfaces from the greylist in Android 9 (API level 28) that are now restricted in Android 10 (API level 29). **Wherever possible, alternative APIs are suggested in a comment following the name of the interface.**

E.g. all common methods reported by Android 9 light greylist filter:

```
Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
```

are now whitelisted in Android 10 so the logcat warn can be safely ignored (at least until Android 11 which may greylist them again :)).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. I just upgraded my `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` and `all dependencies` to the last version and the problem seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You will also get these kind of warnings in the Google Play Console when publishing your app. They appear as 'Stability' warnings in the Pre-launch report.

For now, they are to be ignored as they are beyond your control. If at some point Google updates their SDKs not to use reflection these warnings will disappear.