# Firebase test lab shows me these warnings. Are they really important? Robo test

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I have developed an app and tested it whith firebase test lab and this warning was shown: "Your app uses 2 interfaces that are not part of the SDK and are not supported by Android P and higher." I don´t know if I have to worry about this, does it mean that it won´t be compatible with some android versions? Will the app have more errors because of these warnings? Should I do anything?  These are the two interfaces that are not part of the SDK:

```
Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V
Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I
```

Answer (score 0):

It means it won't be compatible with Anroid versions under 9, which is a bit less than 50% of all devices

Comment: What do you mean about compatible? I am using devices with android versions under 9 and it works perfectly...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This message is saying these API calls may not work properly in Android 9 (Pie, API 28) or later versions, which together account for [over 80% of the US market](https://www.statista.com/statistics/865837/mobile-android-version-share-in-the-us).

These may or may not be actually breaking your app, you have to see that for yourself.

Look around how to debug & fix these, for instance see if this applies: [setContentView is using non-SDK interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358496/setcontentview-is-using-non-sdk-interface)